# Agregarle una condición de mayor a 0 en consulta sql con subconsultas

Tags: mysql, sql, subconsultas

Quisiera poder agregarle una condición de que cuando la columna "ImporteFaltante" (las cual de agrega por medio de un SUBconsulta) sea mayor a 0 se muestre, he intentado de mil formas pero me dice que la columna "ImporteFaltante" No existe.

Un ejemplo del código que realice.

```
SELECT 
    g1.id,
    g1.lote,
    g1.control,
    g1.importe,
    g1.forma_id,
   (select sum(importe) from test.gestion_registro g3 where g3.control = g1.control group by g3.control) as ImporteFaltante
FROM 
test.gestion_registro g1 
where 
g1.id IN (SELECT control  FROM test.gestion_registro g2 GROUP BY g2.control)
AND g1.forma_id = 4
AND g1.ImporteFaltante > 0;
```

Y este es el error que sale:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'g1.ImporteFaltante' in 'where clause'
```

Quiera saber como puede solucionarlo, les dejo por acá un LINK en el cual pueden hacer las pruebas: [Código para pruebas](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c1d7eb/2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 
    g1.id,
    g1.lote,
    g1.control,
    g1.importe,
    g1.forma_id,
   (select sum(importe) from gestion_registro g3 where g3.control = g1.control group by g3.control) as ImporteFaltante
FROM 
gestion_registro g1 
where 
g1.id IN (SELECT control  FROM gestion_registro g2 GROUP BY g2.control)
AND g1.forma_id = 4
) as t where t.ImporteFaltante > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que en el where desconoce el nombre del campo autocalculado, podrías hacer la consulta, como te comenta el compañero generando una nueva tabla, o volviendo a hacer el cálculo de la siguiente forma:

```
 SELECT 
  g1.id,
  g1.lote,
  g1.control,
  g1.importe,
  g1.forma_id,
  select sum(importe) from gestion_registro g3 where g3.control = 
  g1.control group by g3.control) 
 FROM 
    gestion_registro g1 where 
    g1.id IN (SELECT control FROM gestion_registro g2 
            GROUP BY g2.control)                             
AND g1.forma_id = 4
AND (select sum(importe) from gestion_registro g3 where g3.control 
= g1.control group by g3.control)>0;
```

Answer (score 0):

dependiendo de tu version de MySql puedes usar LATERAL para hacer el calculo en una consulta, y tratarlo como un JOIN mas a la tabla, y asi poder usarlo, tanto en el SELECT como en el WHERE

```
SELECT 
    g1.id,
    g1.lote,
    g1.control,
    g1.importe,
    g1.forma_id,
    IMPORTE.ImporteFaltante
FROM test.gestion_registro g1,
LATERAL (
    select (select sum(importe) from test.gestion_registro g3 where g3.control = g1.control group by g3.control) as ImporteFaltante
) as IMPORTE
where 
g1.id IN (SELECT control  FROM test.gestion_registro g2 GROUP BY g2.control)
AND g1.forma_id = 4
AND IMPORTE.ImporteFaltante > 0;
```